# Json Deserialize date

Tags: c#, datetime-format, json-deserialization

I have json file, where date is in the following format:

> 2020-10-14T13:11:51Z

I try to deserialize it using the following settings:

```
        JsonSerializerSettings serSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            DateFormatString = dateFormatString
        };
```

where `dateFormatString` is `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd hh':'mm':'ss"`.

It works fine.

In one case I got date in format:

> 2021-04-13T19:58:042.633Z

It can't be converted using previous format.
I try to write format string for it:

```
dateFormatString = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd hh':'mm':'ss.fff"
```

but it does not work also. What is wrong?

**ADDED**

This unit test success:

```
    [Fact]
    public void DateTimeFormat_JsonDeserialize_YearMonthDayDash24HourClockTime_1()
    {
        string json = @"{ ""Date"" : ""2020-10-14T13:11:51Z"" }";
        JsonSerializerSettings serSettings = JsonParse.GetUsualJsonSerializerSettings(DateTimeFormat.YearMonthDayDash24HourClockTime);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTest>(json, serSettings);

        Assert.Equal(2020, result.Date.Year);
        Assert.Equal(10, result.Date.Month);
        Assert.Equal(14, result.Date.Day);

        Assert.Equal(13, result.Date.Hour);
        Assert.Equal(11, result.Date.Minute);
        Assert.Equal(51, result.Date.Second);
    }
```

but this Unit test is failure:

```
    [Fact]
    public void DateTimeFormat_JsonDeserialize_YearMonthDayDash24HourClockTime_2()
    {
        string json = @"{ ""Date"" : ""2021-04-13T19:58:042.633Z"" }";
        JsonSerializerSettings serSettings = JsonParse.GetUsualJsonSerializerSettings(DateTimeFormat.YearMonthDayDash24HourClockWithMsTime);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTest>(json, serSettings);
    }
```

> Could not convert string to DateTime: 2021-04-13T19:58:042.633Z. Path
> 'Date', line 1, position 38.

I tried different variants of format string:

```
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'fff'.'fff"
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'fff.fff"
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':' ff.fff"
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':' ss.fff"
```

nothing happened.
I see, that problem in this `042` (instead of 2 symbols). How to solve it?

Comment: You should have `HH`, not `hh`. `hh` is a value in the range 1-12.

Comment: FWIW, this looks like the roundtrip datetime format to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet hm, but `2020-10-14T13:11:51Z` (where hours = 13) is allowed for format `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd hh':'mm':'ss"`....

Comment: No it's really not. Certainly not for `DateTime.ParseExact`. Aside from anything else, your format doesn't have a T or a Z... but *also* you want 'HH' rather than 'hh'. If you don't believe me, try the code at https://gist.github.com/jskeet/ae767e23814ef16e8adc5cbabc1d51ae and you'll see an exception. Change 'hh' to 'HH' and it'll work. If you *still* don't believe me, try creating a DateTime with your desired value, and format it with that pattern, and you'll get 01 instead of 13 in the output.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm a little confused. My format string can be used for parsing strings with `hh` and `HH`. But it's only for `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. If I try to use `DateTime.ParseExact` I get `String '2020-10-14T13:11:51Z' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`. What is difference between these 2 ways?

Comment: Your format string has milliseconds. The string you're trying to parse doesn't. I can't easily tell what's going on, and don't have time to try to reproduce the problem without a [mcve] I can just copy/paste, but you *really, really* should accept that `hh` is for 12-hour hour-of-day, and `HH` is for 24-hour.

Comment: The letter `T` in your samples is not found in your format strings.  This is a literal that must be specified.